# Mode of convergence for partial Fourier series in $B( L_p[-\pi; \pi ])$, $p \in [1; \infty]$

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Which mode of convergence takes place, strong, weak, or in norm?
If we have sequence of continuous linear operators in $L_p[-\pi; \pi]$:

$(A_n x)(t) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k cos(kt) + b_k sin(kt)$

Where

$a_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x(t) cos(kt) dx$

$b_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x(t) sin(kt) dx$

Comment: It's mostly frowned upon to ask homework questions without showing any working you have done.. _we're not_ here to do your work for you.

Comment: I have no idea where to start, maybe there is some information in books related to this, or smth...